# How to replace comma in .xlsx file in ColdFusion?

Tags: excel, csv, coldfusion

I have excel file that can contain commas in some fields. This can cause problem if I want to use `cfspreadsheet` to convert my file to `csv`. I was wondering if there is the way to `replace` or `convert` all commas with the `\`. After I replace all commas then I will be able to use `cfspreadsheet` to create `csv`. Here is my code how I read my file:

```
<cfspreadsheet action = "read" format="csv" src="filePath\myFile.xlsx" name="csvvar">
```

If anyone can help with this problem please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: cfhttp might be a better tag choice than cfspreadsheet for this situation.  Details are in the documentation.  However, having said that, your csv file would have to have the data double quoted in order to determine which commas are delimiters and which are part of the data.

Comment: @DanBracuk I want to replace commas before I create csv file. My file is in .xlsx and I want to replace , with \ that way my csv will skip all \. Also can you provide any example of how that can be done with cfhttp tag?

Comment: I misunderstood the question.  I thought you were trying to read a csv file.  Having said that, if the intent is to create a csv file, I recommend double quoting all the data cells so that commas in the data will matter less.

Comment: @DanBracuk So you are recommending putting quotes around each field and then run export to csv? Is there any chance that data still can be invalid or different if any of the fields has the commas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What I really recommend is that you do what I just did.  Use excel to create a csv file where some of the cells contain commas.  Then open the file with notepad and look at the content.

Comment: @DanBracuk  I tried just to output to csv and my field that contains commas looks like this "Test, comma ". I'm wondering how this can be presented as an value without quotes.

Comment: Open the file with excel again and see if the quotes are there.

Answer (score 1):

Convert from Excel to query. Then, in the cell data of each row, replace "," by "\". Something like this

```
<cfspreadsheet 
action = "read" 
src="filePath\myFile.xlsx" 
query="excelquery" 
sheet="1">

<!--- Create CSV file in current directory--->
<cffile action="write" file="#expandpath('result.csv')#" output="">

<cfset columns = arraynew(1)>
  <!--- Store the list of column names as an array --->
<cfset columns = listToArray(excelquery.ColumnList)>

<cfoutput query="excelquery">
<cfset rowList = "">

<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(columns)#" index="n">
    <cfset colName = columns[n]>
    <cfset cellData = evaluate("#colName#[currentrow]")>

    <!--- Replace , by \ in each cell --->
    <cfset cellData = replace(cellData, ",", "\", "all")>

    <!--- Comma-separated row data --->
    <cfset rowList = listAppend(rowList,cellData)>
</cfloop>

<!--- Place a carriage-return at the end of the row --->
<cfset rowList = rowList & '<br>'>

<!--- Append row to CSV file --->
<cffile action="append" file="#expandpath('result.csv')#" output="#rowList#" >
</cfoutput>
```