# How to create tab delimited text file from cfquery?

Tags: excel, coldfusion, text-files, xlsx, cfspreadsheet

I have created `query` using `cfspreadsheet`. Now I'm wondering if it's possible to convert query to tab delimited text file. This is my code to get the query:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="C:\myFiles\Records.xlsx" query="myQuery" headerrow="1">
```

Here is the list of my records from excel represented in cfquery:

```
    FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   DOB     GENDER  
1   FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   DOB     GENDER 
2   Mike    Johns   01/12/98    M   
3   Helen   Johns   2/2/01  F
```

I would like my text file to look like this if possible:

```
FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   DOB     GENDER 
Mike    Johns   01/12/98    M   
Helen   Johns   2/2/01  F
```

Tab delimiter between the values and \n to create newline. I have tried `.csv` but I could not get file organized as I showed above. Also if there is any other way to convert `.xlsx` file to `.txt` please let me know. I was looking `xp_cmdshell` commands but there is nothing that would be helpful in my case.

Here si the code that I used to get .csv file:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" format="csv" src="C:\myFiles\Records.xlsx" name="myCsv">
```

Then I used `FileWrite()` to get .txt file:

```
<cfscript> 
    FileWrite("C:\myFiles\Records.txt", "#myCsv#"); 
</cfscript>
```

Code above gave me tab delimited text file but one problem occured, if value in the field was empty those columns disappeared. For example if I did not have value in my GENDER column, that column was not created.

```
Mike    Johns   01/12/98
```

Comment: You have been around long enough to know the drill ;-)  Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @Leigh question updated.

Comment: I don't think there is any RFC 4180 compliant function in CF (`cfspreadsheet action="write"` is quite janky). You'll have to write a function yourself. Hint: There's more than just empty columns, think of tabs and newlines within your query values.

Comment: I'd be using the cffile tags myself.

Answer (score 1):

You may see this literally as a question of converting a query result-set into a tab-delimited CSV file. That is, without the involvement of cfspreadsheet. You will get an answer by slightly modifying [the answer I gave to a similar question from you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721441/how-to-replace-comma-in-xlsx-file-in-coldfusion/40752479#40752479):

```
<cfspreadsheet 
action = "read" 
src="C:\myFiles\Records.xlsx" 
query="excelquery" 
sheet="1">

<!--- Create CSV file in current directory--->
<cffile action="write" file="#expandpath('result.csv')#" output="">

<cfset columns = arraynew(1)>
<cfset columns = listToArray(excelquery.ColumnList)>

<cfoutput query="excelquery">
<cfset rowList = "">

<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(columns)#" index="n">
    <cfset colName = columns[n]>
    <cfset cellData = evaluate("#colName#[currentrow]")>

    <!--- Tab-separated row data --->
    <cfset rowList = listAppend(rowList,cellData,chr(9))>
</cfloop>

<!--- Place carriage-return at end of row --->
<cfset rowList = rowList & '<br>'>

<!--- Append row to CSV file --->
<cffile action="append" file="#expandpath('result.csv')#" output="#rowList#" >
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Why are you using an html tag for a carriage return?

Comment: @DanBracuk Can we use chr(13) or chr(10) ?

Comment: @BKBK I have tried code above and first problem is extra row between each row of data. Second problem all data is in the same cell, looks like tab delimiter command does not work in line of code where ListAppend().